# Problems with calculation of Gaussian curvature of $S^{2}.$

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, spheres

I know that there is a lot of computations of Gaussain Curvature of $S^{2}$, but I'm trying my on way.

Just to simplify, I'm dealing with points in the north hemisphere, that is, where $z=0.$

I'm using this parametrization:

$$\mathbb{x}(u,v)=\left(u,v,\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}\right). $$

So, $$\Bbb{x}_{u}=\left(1,0,-u(1-u^2-v^2)^{-1/2}\right), \\
\mathbb{x}_{v}=\left(0,1,-v(1-u^2-v^2)^{-1/2}\right).$$

So, the coefficients of the first fundamental form are

$$E=\frac{1-v^{2}}{1-u^2-v^2},\;F=\frac{uv}{1-u^2-v^2},\;G=\frac{1-u^2}{1-u^2-v^2} \\
\implies EG-F^{2}=1. $$

I think that, till here, there is nothing wrong.

Now, I want to find $e,g,f$.

$$\mathbb{x}_{uu}=\left(0,0,-u^{2}(1-u^2-v^2)^{-3/2}\right),\\
\Bbb{x}_{vv}=\left(0,0,-v^{2}(1-u^2-v^2)^{-3/2}\right), \\
\mathbb{x}_{uv}=\left(0,0,-uv(1-u^2-v^2)^{-3/2}\right).$$

To compute the normal $N$, we can do:

$$N=\Bbb{x}_{u}\wedge\Bbb{x}_{v}=\det\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & -u(1-u^{2}-v^{2})^{-1/2}) \\
0 & 1 & -v(1-u^{2}-v^{2})^{-1/2}) \\
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k}
\end{array}
\right] \\
\implies N=\left(\frac{u}{1-u^2-v^2},\frac{v}{1-u^2-v^2},1\right) $$

So, we have the coefficients of the second fundamental form:

$$e=\left<\Bbb{x}_{uu},N\right>=\frac{-u^2}{(1-u^2-v^2)^{-3/2}} \\
f= \left<\Bbb{x}_{uv},N\right>=\frac{-uv}{(1-u^2-v^2)^{-3/2}} \\
g=\left<\Bbb{x}_{vv},N\right>=\frac{-v^2}{(1-u^2-v^2)^{-3/2}}$$

Now I see that there is a problem. See that

$$eg-f^2=\frac{u^2v^2-u^2v^2}{(1-u^2-v^2)^{3}}=0. $$

Since $K=\frac{eg-f^2}{EG-F^2},$ this would imply $K=0$, and this is obviously wrong.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Check again your $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculated $EG-F^2$ incorrectly. You should get $$EG-F^2=\frac{1}{1-u^2-v^2}.$$ This will change your $N$ to $$N=\left(u,v,\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}\right).$$ After calculating
 \begin{align*}
x_{uu}&=\left(0,0,\frac{v^2-1}{(1-u^2-v^2)^{3/2}}\right)\\
x_{uv}&=\left(0,0,\frac{-uv}{(1-u^2-v^2)^{3/2}}\right)\\
x_{uu}&=\left(0,0,\frac{u^2-1}{(1-u^2-v^2)^{3/2}}\right),
\end{align*}
you'll get

\begin{align*}
e&=\frac{v^2-1}{{1-u^2-v^2}}\\
f&=\frac{-uv}{{1-u^2-v^2}}\\
g&=\frac{u^2-1}{{1-u^2-v^2}}.
\end{align*} Now, you can conclude that $$K=\frac{eg-f^2}{EG-F^2}=1.$$